# how to play a music by notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

I used a notification that call a player service and this player should play a music.
But I don't know how to play in background?

you can see my code the following :

1.First File call player service

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);

i.putExtra(PlayerService.EXTRA_PLAYLIST, "main");
i.putExtra(PlayerService.EXTRA_SHUFFLE, true);

startService(i);
```

2.Second file is a class for play a music

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public static final String EXTRA_PLAYLIST="EXTRA_PLAYLIST";
    public static final String EXTRA_SHUFFLE="EXTRA_SHUFFLE";
    private boolean isPlaying=false;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String playlist=intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PLAYLIST);
        boolean useShuffle=intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHUFFLE, false);

        play(playlist, useShuffle);       
        return(START_NOT_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return(null);
    }

    private void play(String playlist, boolean useShuffle) {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Got to play()!");
            isPlaying=true;

            Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat, "Can you hear the music?", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent i=new Intent(this, FakePlayer.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,i, 0);

            note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Fake Player","Now Playing: \"Ummmm, Nothing\"", pi);
            note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

            startForeground(1337, note);
        }
    }
    private void stop() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Got to stop()!");
            isPlaying=false;
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks and Regards, Omid

Comment: Please consider rephrasing the question, it is unclear (to me at least). What are you exactly looking for? A media player that plays in the background of your app/activity?

Comment: I want to play a long sound when downloading a package. then, in notification both show a progress bar and play sound.

Answer (score 1):

Probably You have already found the answer, but maybe it will be helpfull to someone else. Namely, Notification class has [sound](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#sound) method, that requires path to the file one wants to play on notification occurence. See [notification examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (expecially "Adding a sound" paragraph) for more information.